# How to get JavaScript Object values as comma separated and quoted String?

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
const a = 
{
      "id": "A",
      "value": "100",
      "number": "1"
  };

console.log(Object.values(a).join(','));
```

**Actual Response**

```
A,100,1
```

**Expected Response**

```
''A','100','1''
```

Comment: You gotta map first to add the quotes, and then join.  Or `"'"+ Object.values(a).join("','") + "'"`

Comment: You will need to wrap each value in quotes before putting the array through `join`. However, why not just use `JSON.stringify`, which also gives you proper escaping?

Comment: You've sort of lost which property each item belongs with in the expected response.  You're relying on the order of properties always being the same.  It would be better to explicitly have a property order in an array somewhere if you plan on doing this "For realz"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` method

```js
const a = {
  "id": "A",
  "value": "100",
  "number": "1"
};

console.log(`'${Object.values(a).map(v => `'${v}'`).join(',')}'`);


// or JSON stringify 
console.log(`"${Object.values(a).map(v => JSON.stringify(v)).join(',')}"`);
```

Comment: what is the use of `" ?

Comment: Those denote a **template literal** that allow for string construction through *interpolation*.  Essentially injecting variables into a string without having to write the concatenation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `mapping` as follows:

```js
const a = 
{
   "id": "A",
   "value": "100",
   "number": "1"
};

console.log(
    Object.values(a).map(v => {
        return `'${v}'`
    }).join(",")
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can join on `','` and then add the outer quotes around them.

```js
const a = {
  "id": "A",
  "value": "100",
  "number": "1"
};

console.log(
  `'${Object.values(a).join("','")}'`
);
```